# Jquery math operation inside a method

Tags: jquery, math, methods

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
var $ul = $('.f-ul');
var ulMT = $ul.css("marginTop");
$ul.css({"marginTop":"" + math(ulMT+40) + ""px","opacity":"0"});
```

But I know this is wrong. Any solution please ?

Comment: "_But I know this is wrong_." How do you know?

Comment: Someones Inspires me :D

Comment: Someone inspires you? To do what?

Comment: @Pay4m, I think you mean "notified" or "informed" instead of "inspired".  What the others are trying to ask you is what part exactly is wrong? What is the expected behavior? What is actually happening? etc.

Comment: thanks for -1 , but I know it's wrong because it's not working. Maybe I should have written "It's not working", then this question wouldn't have popped up in your mind :) And Claps for those who know everything :)

Comment: If you would have written "It's not working", then the question would be the same; How do you know? To say that something isn't working is useless information unless you also provide the information about how it should work, and in what way it fails to do that.

Comment: what information can explain more than "It's not working" while I've shown what I mean to do by this code ? Alex Wayne Understood I'm trying to put a math operation at middle of a method property which I doubt being like a string !!!!

Comment: @Pay4m there was obvious syntax error, which is the only reason I knew. What you should of said was "This code cause the browser to return 'SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier'." If you said that, it would be clear it doesn't work and why. You don't have to know how to fix it, but you should be able to say specifically how it's broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ul.css({"marginTop":"" + math(ulMT+40) + ""px","opacity":"0"});
//                                        ^^ syntax error
```

Aside from that syntax error, it should work fine. Notice how the syntax highlighting gets all screwy at that point? That should be your first clue of improperly terminated strings.

If you remove that extra " you get:

```
$ul.css({"marginTop":"" + math(ulMT+40) + "px","opacity":"0"});
```

---

I was assuming that you were defining a function called `math` somewhere. In case you aren't, and all you you want to do is add two numbers, you don't need that `math()` call at all.

```
$ul.css({"marginTop":"" + (ulMT+40) + "px","opacity":"0"});
```

---

Also, might I suggest a little bit of editing so this is easier to read?

```
$ul.css({
  marginTop: "" + (ulMT+40) + "px",
  opacity: "0"
});
```

---

Finally, `$ul.css("marginTop");` does not return a number. It returns a string like `"16px"`. Which means you are doing something like this:

```
var ulMT = "16px";
var newMT = ulMT + 40 + "px";
console.log(newMt); // "46px40px"
```

That's not what you want. You need to parse that margin value as an integer so you can use it for math. This is done with `parseInt(x, 10);` where `x` is the string that you need as an integer.

```
var ulMT = parseInt($ul.css("marginTop"), 10);
```

Proof it works: http://jsfiddle.net/cYDU2/

Comment: browser is giving this error : ReferenceError: math is not defined

Comment: I assumed you had defined a function called `math`... See my edit

Comment: But it seems the Addition operation is not working. In firefox Console I'm changing "40" in `$ul.css({"marginTop":"" + (ulMT+40) + "px","opacity":"1"})` but nothing changes. but by changing opacity, it changes!

Comment: Probably because it's `margin-top` not `marginTop`. `$ul.css({"margin-top":` Maybe you should slow down. Get it working a little at a time. In this case, prove you can set the margin with a static value, then try change that be a dynamic value set with a math calculation. This prevents you from have multiple big problems at once.

Comment: yes, it works : `$ul.css({"marginTop":"10px","opacity":"1"})`, but it does not work : `$ul.css({"marginTop":"" + (ulMT+50) + "px","opacity":"1"})` also I changed marginTop to margin-top, no difference ( they are the same as far as I know )

Comment: See my latest edit. Again, _slow down_. get something simpler working first, and once that is working modify it one tiny piece at a time until so you are sure what part is breaking.

Comment: yes, thank you so much, it's now working <3 just a question, what is that "10" in parseInt() method ?

Comment: It says the number is base 10, otherwise it guesses. More info: http://davidwalsh.name/parseint-radix